# Bootstrap 3 Still Renders Hidden classes with ASP.NET MVC @Html.Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In my html View page, I have the following div that has a responsive Bootstrap class of hidden-xs. This class hides the content when viewing on small mobile devices.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
    @Html.Partial("_partialView")
</div>
```

But viewing the html source, I still see the HTML getting loaded. How do I use the "Mobile First" approach and only load partial views / html ONLY when it is applicable to my view ports? Without this, I am putting a strain on mobile download speeds.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what happens when you use responsive web design. By necessity, sharing the same codebase between mobile, tablet, and desktop means that they all have to load the same document and then render it accordingly.

If you want to completely omit sections of view for mobile devices (i.e. "xs"), you'll need to look into ASP.NET MVC's mobile support instead: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.